# Matter-antimatter conversion in quarks

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, antimatter, quarks

If in beta plus decay, regular matter such as the up quark can decay into a positron, I have to wonder under high pressure, could it be possible for a quark to decay into the antiquark of its opposite?

For example, if we have a down quark under high pressure, could it decay into say an anti-up quark? Since antimatter has equal and opposite charge and weak isospin, I'm guessing that this wouldn't break any conservation laws. Therefore, could this process take place or is there some other reason I don't know about?

Answer (score 2):

Beware that

> the up quark can decay into a positron

suggests an interaction like

$$
\rm u\to e^+
$$

which does *not* occur. The symmetries that are broken are the conservation of “baryon number” and “lepton number.” A better decay equation is

$$
\rm u \to d + e^+  + \nu_e
$$

Now both sides contain one-third of a baryon, $B=1/3$, and both sides contain an equal number of leptons versus antileptons, $L=0$.

We don’t actually know *why* baryon number and lepton number are preserved. In fact, we have reason to believe that they are *not* exact symmetries, because the universe contains an excess of baryons over antibaryons.

Answer (score 1):

You guessed wrong. The charges 2/3, -1/3, 1/3, -2/3 for $u, d, \bar{d}, \bar{u}$ are all different.